# Elasticsearch query starting from a particular value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Is there a way to query starting from a particular value and get the next n records in Elasticsearch?

For example, I want to get 10 records starting from employee id "ABC_123".
The below query gives an error saying

> [terms] query does not support [empId]

```
GET /_search
{   
    "from": 0, "size": 10,
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "empId" : "ABC_123"
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: use empId.keyword. For terms field must be of type "non_analyzer" / "keyword". Are you looking for pagination in terms query

Comment: @jaspreetchahal, terms query will not list all the values starting from `ABC_123`, he needs to pass exact value to get the results from terms query, while he wants to get results starting from specific value, for example empId can be `ABC_123123` and searching for `ABC_123` should bring it

Comment: I am not sure of Index mapping since i don't have admin access. The prefix query returns only 1 record because the empId is UUID format. The requirement is to start pagination of all the records starting from the searched emp id or name. The sample doc is { "id":"123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000", "name":"Bob"} {"id":"456e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655441234", "name":"Jack"}.....The cursor should start from searched record id/name. Thanks!

Comment: @santosh, if your empid is stored as keyword, then prefix query should return all the result, I myself tested created sample docs and searched it, did you get a chance to look at my answer, also see if you have access to _mapping to get the index mapping?

Comment: @santosh when you say "get the next n records", that automatically implies a sort order. What would your sort order be in this case?

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote? I wrote an answer with all the little details available and it's sad to see community member just downvoting without explaining the reason

Comment: @santosh, did you get a chance to check it again and let me know if hv further questions

Comment: Yet to get access to _mapping to get index mapping.

Comment: The sort order should be ascending. If there are say 1000 records, page size is 100, if the given id is 101th rec then it should start from page 2 to 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), Also you can read more about the [autocomplete on my blog](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/), which discussed 4 approaches to make it work and their trade-off.

**I used prefix query on your sample data and got the expected output and below is the step by step guide.**

### Index mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "empId": {
                "type": "keyword" --> field type `keyword`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample docs

```
{
  "empId" : "ABC_1231"
}

{
  "empId" : "ABC_1232"
}

{
  "empId" : "ABC_1233"
}

{
  "empId" : "ABC_1234"
}
```

and so on

### Prefix Search query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "empId": "ABC_123"
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_prefix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "empId": "ABC_1231"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_prefix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "empId": "ABC_1232"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_prefix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "empId": "ABC_1233"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_prefix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "empId": "ABC_1234"
        }
      }
    ]
```